# Lucene indexing and searching at the same time

Tags: java, search, tomcat, lucene, indexing

I want to search with Lucene on an index. The index is changed frequently. So I need to do something to search and index at the same time. It's a web application on Tomcat. And I want to use RAMDeirectory to increase the searching speed. I don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NRTManager` in the `misc` Lucene package provides the ability to search and index at the same time.

```
TrackingIndexWriter writer; // your writer
SearcherFactory factory = new SearcherFactory();
NRTManager mgr = new NRTManager(writer, factory);
```

Check NRTManager methods for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You can search and index at the same time using the same index.  Look at Lucene's [near real time search](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/NearRealtimeSearch).

Some example code from the wiki,

```
IndexWriter writer; // create an IndexWriter here
Document doc = null; // create a document here
writer.addDocument(doc); // update a document
IndexReader reader = writer.getReader(); // get a reader with the new doc
Document addedDoc = reader.document(0);
```

Comment: How can I search on that index, then!?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that either doing a

1. Batch/overnight operations rebuilding the indexes.
2. Do that asynch way....

Depends on the requirement, what latency you need.

Comment: How to alternate indices without making the web app down!?