# Changing Lucene Searcher on Running Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, lucene

I have an index which should be updated so frequently (See [Lucene indexing and searching at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256226/lucene-indexing-and-searching-at-the-same-time)). So first I make the index-1 and then put the lucene IndexSearcher on it. The web application on Tomcat uses it on the Servlet for users to search. Then, I make index-2 (updated!). I want to change the IndexSearcher to the new index and delete the old index (index-1), without downing my web application on Tomcat. Any ideas!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new NRTManager. Reopening entire indexes is BAD.

Comment: It's not well documented. Read the JavaDocs, and Mike Mcandless's Changing Bits blog. (Though the api changed a bit since he published that). Point is: You open one indexwriter, and close it only when app terminates. The NRTManager gets instantiated as a singleton with this indexwriter. You then obtain Indexsearchers only from the NRTManager, and remember to return them. You then get Near Realtime Search - meaning changes are reflected in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two indexes. You can use only one IndexWriter in application and on each new search create a IndexSearch in following way

```
  IndexWriter indexWriter;

  public List search(){
    IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(indexWriter, false);
    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader); 

    //do search and return answer

  }
```

In this case the performance will be pretty good. I used Lucene 3.5.